# Is there an elegant way to read a SQL-Dump file in python with the help of sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a sql dump file containing a db that i need to query over.

Problem is that i dont have a local db installation and wont get one due to it restrictions.

Can I read in my dump via python in sqlite3? i couldn't find a proper explanation on how to do so.

Pretty new to stackoverflow.

I've used this code snippet I found online to iterate my dump and at least get all table names in return:

```
table_list=[]
with open(dmp.file ,encoding='cp437') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.lower().startswith('create table'):
            table_name = re.findall('create table `([\w_]+)`', line.lower())
            table_list.extend(table_name)
            
for x in table_list:
    print(x)
```

This worked fine, however in my dump statements for creating tables and so on go over multiple lines, so this approach doesn't work neatly anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this snippet to write all statements to one row each.

```
currentLine = ""
with open(File,encoding='cp437') as f:
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    currentLine = currentLine + " " + line
    if line.lower().endswith(';') == True:
        with open(NewFileOneLiner.txt', "a", encoding="utf-8") as g:
            g.write(currentLine.lstrip() + '\n')
            currentLine = ""
```