sqlite3.DataError: query string is too large
I'm trying to analyze this wiktionary dump with is 5GB, but I'm getting the above error message in the title.  Here is my code:
    import sqlite3
    conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
    c = conn.cursor()
    sql_file = open(f'wiktionary_categories.sql',encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
    sql_as_string = sql_file.read()
    c.executescript(sql_as_string)

Is there some way I can use a with statement? Such as:
    with open(f'wiktionary_categories.sql',encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as sql_file:
        sql_as_string = sql_file.read()
        c.executescript(sql_as_string)

I just want to run through the file and pick out all of the words that belong to a certain category.

so you dont necessarily need to run all the statements but just get some words?

maybe this will help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78039596/way-of-executing-mariadb-sql-statements-with-python-and-sqlite3 had a similar problem in the past

sqlparse module might help to split into smaller queries https://pypi.org/project/sqlparse/

Avoid calling read() on large files since you read all at once into a single string. Usually, you want to iterate across lines. See I/O docs.

It took me a while to figure out but the sql file is basically just a text file.  You loop over the lines and then you execute the sql statements that you need.  You can just open it with a with statement.
